# [ERROR] Client wants topic /xxx but our version has /yyy

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am trying to execute some trajectories on my robot using the [simple_trajectory.cpp tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Moving%20the%20arm%20using%20the%20Joint%20Trajectory%20Action).

I am able to see my controller using rostopic echo /r_arm_controller and it shows me everything I want. However when I execute my moves I get this error:

```
[ERROR] [1360184059.110097449]: Client [/right_joint_trajectory_action] wants topic /r_arm_controller/joint_trajectory_action/goal to have datatype/md5sum [control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionGoal/8f3e00277a7b5b7c60e1ac5be35ddfa2], but our version has [pr2_controllers_msgs/JointTrajectoryActionGoal/aee77e81e3afb8d91af4939d603609d8]. Dropping connection.
```

It looks pretty self explanitory but I wanted some claification. So my action server uses [control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionGoal] for topic of publishing on and my action client uses [pr2_controllers_msgs/JointTrajectoryActionGoal]. Which of these should I conform to?

I am not using a pr2 robot so I am thinking of using control_msgs, but I want to know if one is better than the other. Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54494/%5Berror%5D-client-wants-topic-/xxx-but-our-version-has-/yyy/) by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2013-02-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the answer, the pr2_controller_msgs/JointTrajectoryActionGoal is an old method of using the joint trajectory action control. I changed over the tutorial code to use:

```
#include <control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryAction.h>
```

instead of:

```
#include <pr2_controllers_msgs/JointTrajectoryAction.h>
```

and any calls like:

```
pr2_controllers_msgs::JointTrajectoryGoal
```

to:

```
control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryGoal
```

Works fine but now I'm encountering [a different run-time error](http://answers.ros.org/question/54510/error-when-sending-from-trajclient/), however I don't know the cause of this one yet. I will try to update if I find an answer!

Regards,
Martin

---

Originally posted by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) with karma: 464 on 2013-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0